# MongoDB: How do you create an index on a field which is nested in two arrays?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongo schema which essentially has two nested arrays, each of which contain objects. I would like to create an index on a field nested in that second level array. The schema looks as such:

```
const restaurantsSchema = new Schema({
  restaurantName: { type: String, required: true },
  dishes: [{
    dishName: String,
    price: Number,
    description: String,
    reviews: [{
      reviewId: Number,  **<<<< INDEX THIS FIELD**
      userId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users',
        required: true,
      },
      photoUrl: String,
      caption: String,
      createdAt: Number,
      updatedAt: Number,
      rating: Number,
      reviewText: String,
    }],
  }],
});
```

The idea is that I can use this index to find and update a user's reviews. Is this possible with Mongo's multikey indexing or is there another way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you change the schema to

```
reviewId: {
    type: Number,
    unique: true
}
```

mongodb automatically creates an index because each value should be unique. That really the only qualification for creating any index.

write back if it works!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This would work on the Mongoose side if I inserted records one by one, I suppose, but the problem is that I need to batch insert millions of records to seed the database for testing. Doing this with Mongoose is not really feasible. So, I need to apply the index to an already existing data set.